# git file getting deleted again and again

Tags: git, github

I cloned a project and I can see using the Web UI that there are 3 files.

After cloning, I noticed I only got 2 files. I checked the branch and I'm on master and I should have 3 files.

Here is output of `git status` :

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    con.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But I didn't delete any file !

`git ls-files --deleted` : `con.js`

Ok, weird bug, I then try to restore the file that strangely got deleted while cloning so I type `git checkout con.js`.

After I type `git checkout con.js`, the full file get printed in the terminal. I suspect it gets deleted again immediatly.
If I then type `git ls-files --deleted`, `con.js` it is still there and not restored !

What could I be possibly doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sharing this repository someone else who has different OS than you? Sometimes renaming directories between case sensitive/case insensitive local repositories creates this weird situation

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı It's a fork from another repo. I don't know main dev OS. But the file is at the root of the project, not in any directory, and it doesn't contain any specific characters.

Comment: @AnonBird are you on Windows?

Comment: @sbat yes i am.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8,
> COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also
> avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example,
> NUL.txt is not recommended.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Git expectedly has many issues with files like aux.js, con.cpp, etc on Windows. Your best bet is to rename this file in the repo.

Comment: One of these days, I'm going to make a repo consisting of files with no names *except* these. :-)